# Updating Parent state with function passed as prop to Child

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to refresh the `Parent` Component's state once `ChildForm` invokes a function passed as a prop. My component is structured like below.

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {data: []};
    }

    getThings() {
        //Working ajax get request for data
    }

    updateThing(obj){
        $.ajax({
          url: `/api/update/${obj.identifier}`,
          dataType: 'json',
          type: 'POST',
          data: obj,
          success: (res) => {
              this.getThings();
          },
          error: (xhr, status, err) => {
            console.error(`/api/update/${obj.identifier}`, status, err.toString());
          }
        });
    }

    componentDiMount() {
        this.getThings();
    }

    render() {
        let childForms = this.state.data.map((x, i) => {
            return (
                <ChildForm key={i} id={`thing${i}`} {...x} update={this.updateThing} />
            );
        });
        let dataVisuals = this.state.data.map((x, i) => {
            return (
                <DataViz key={i} {...x} />
            );
        });
        return (
            <div>
                {dataVisuals}
                {childForms}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class ChildForm extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {...props};
        this.handleUpdate = this.handleUpdate.bind(this);
    }
    handleInputChange() {
        ///working input functionality to update form state
    }
    handleUpdate() {
        let obj = {...this.state};
        this.props.update(obj);
    }
    render() {
        //Form for updating individual thing
    }
}
```

When ChildForm invokes this.props.update, The record updates successfully on the db, but I get an error that `this.getThings()` is not a function and the `Parent` component is not updated. How can I trigger the state update on `Parent`?

**EDIT**: Sorry, forgot to show that I had `this.handleUpdate = this.handleUpdate.bind(this);` in `ChildForm` constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### What happened

Although you passed the `this.updateThing` to `<ChildForm />`, but when this function being invoked in `update` of the `<ChildForm />`, the context is changed, which caused the `undefined` for `this.getThings()`

### How to fix

Using bind to replace the this when the function being called in ChildForm.

Quote from MDN:

> The bind() method creates a new function that, when called, has its this keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

So, have a try for replace `update={this.updateThing}` with `update={this.updateThing.bind(this)}`

Comment: SMH. I thought I had tried that on the fifteen variations of `bind()` that I had tried. Thank you.